# How to set a string as page HTML/Javascript code to use with re.findall

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I am parsing the HTML/Javascript code of a page using regex and looking for any code between '[]'. I am doing this like so:

```
regex = r'[.*?]'
string =  #point to website html here
myfinder = re.findall(regex, string)
```

As the title of this post suggests, I am not sure how I define a a string as being the HTML content of a page. I should point out that I am using a CrawlSpider class within Scrapy to crawl multiple pages of the same website, where I know that multiple pages will have the data I want stored in this format.

Can anyone provide me with a solution?

Thanks

Comment: For one, your regex is incorrect. You need to escape the brackets to match a literal. Right now you have characters that the regex engine sees stored inside a character class. And you're better off using a parser...

Comment: use a HTML parser to parse html files. I think your regex needs multiline modifier. `myfinder = re.findall(regex, string, re.M)` and also don't forget to escape `[]` in your regex. `r'\[.*?\]'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj hi, i am quite new to python. could you please provide me with the exact syntax i will need as i dont quite understand your answer. thanks.

Comment: your regex line would be `regex = r'\[.*?\]'`, and your findall line would be `myfinder = re.findall(regex, string, re.M)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj ok thanks. with regards to a html parser i am familiar with things like xpath and css selectors, but i have only used them to target specific things like paragraphs. what syntax would i need to use in this instance?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: `re.M` doesn't change what match the dot. it changes only the meaning of anchors `^` and `$`. To allow the dot to match newlines, the option is `re.S` or `re.Singleline`

Comment: yep. if the input contains `[foo\nbar]` then it's better to use `re.S`

Answer (score 0):

When used with Scrapy the following will return anything on the page that is contained within two square brackets:

```
regex = r'\[.*?\]'
        match2 = re.findall(regex, response.body, re.S)
        print match2
```